# ruby on rails: ElasticSearch / Tire dynamic search on multiple indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I've done a bunch of searching and I haven't been able to get an answer to this question - hopefully this isn't a repeat (apologies if it is)...

Preface:  I'm using Rails & Tire to perform ElasticSearch.

I have an object, Place, with attributes "name", "city", "state", and "zip".  They are indexed as follows:

```
indexes :name, :type => 'multi_field', :fields => { 
  :name => { :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball' }, 
  :"name.exact" => { :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed } 
} 
indexes :city 
indexes :state 
indexes :zip
```

There are three conditions for searching:  1. Name only, 2. (City, State OR Zip), 3. Name AND (City, State OR Zip).

My code for the "query" block is:

```
  if (City, State).present? 
    boolean do 
      must { string "name:#{name}*" } if name.present? 
      must { string "city:#{city_state}*" } 
      must { string "state:#{city_state}*" } 
    end 
  elsif (Zip).present? 
    boolean do 
      must { string "name:#{name}*" } if name.present? 
      must { string "zip:#{query_parameters["zip"]}*" } 
    end 
  else 
    string "name:#{name}*" } 
  end
```

The aforementioned search conditions #1 and #2 work as expected against multiple tests.  However, condition 3 does not - it seems to only pay attention to the "name" field.  I'm assuming it has something to do with using the "city_state" variable to search on both "city" and "state"... But I'm doing this because a user can enter either "Chicago" or "Illinois" in the City, State / Zip text box and the search should still work, using either the geographic center of Chicago or the geographic center of Illinois, respectively.

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> However, condition 3 does not - it seems to only pay attention to the "name" field

Errr, isn't

```
string "name:#{name}*"
```

telling it to do exactly that?

or did you mean to just do

```
string "#{name}"
```

Comment: To clarify:  The three conditions are:  There are three conditions for searching: 1. Name only, 2. (City, State OR Zip), 3. Name AND (City, State OR Zip).  So, Name && (City, State || Zip) doesn't work.